# css float: Clear and float none doesnt work

Tags: css, reactjs, css-float

Here is my code:

```
<div id="root">
   <img src={clock} alt="clock" title="Fast and simple!" id="clockEslogan"/>
   <p className="phrase">Know developers for your proyects in no time</p>
   <p className="buffer"></p>
   <p className="phrase">Join open-source proyects in no time</p>
</div>
```

The problem that I have is the first and second phrase, I am trying to break the float of the two elements and have something like these:

[image]

And i am having these:

[image]

But i cant, i have been doing clear: both; and float: none; with a buffer and putting a class to the two objects but thy are sticked together with the float effect, here is my CSS code:

```
#clockEslogan {
  width: 120px;
  float: left;
  margin-right: 15px;
}

.buffer {
  clear: both;
  float: none;
}
```

Is there something I am doing wrong?

Comment: Your question is not clear enough. Please elaborate. what's your initial css? what do you want to 'break' ?

Comment: what's the purpose of `buffer`? is it to make space between `firstPhrase` and `secondPhrase` ?

Comment: Hi, I am using React so that is all the css that i have, I updated the code for the phrases and I want to break the two words that appear in the image. As I said in the quesion the buffer was an attempt of breaking the float. Thanks for the suggestions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I personally prefer to use flexbox for this sort of thing, but here is a float solution. It is neater to contain them with a div which you can apply extra styling to and just let paragraphs do their thing as block elements. But floated elements will want to sit next to each other if you don't set their width to take up more space.

```css
#clockEslogan {
  width: 120px;
  float: left;
  margin-right: 15px;
  background:#ccc;
  padding:20px;
}
#phrase {
/*No floats here*/
}
/*set a width here if you need to */
#phrase-container {
float:left;
}
#buffer {
clear:both;
}
```

```html
<div id="clockEslogan">
  [Pretend I'm an Image]
</div>
<div id="phrase-container">
  <p class="phrase">Know helpers for your project in no time</p>
  <p class="phrase">Join open-source projects in no time</p>
</div>
<div id="buffer"></div>
<div>More content to demonstrate the flow;</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Not exactly sure of the question. But let's give it a try.

So you want to seperate the two paragraphs? It appears that your paragraphs may have a `display: inline-block;`. So remove your `buffer` class from the css and add this.

```
#root p.buffer {
    display: block;
}
```